# Trying to install linux on Sony Vaio with a bootable USB

Tags: linux, boot, usb, sony-vaio

I have a Sony Vaio from 2009.

https://www.sony-asia.com/electronics/support/laptop-pc-vpc-series/vpcw125aa/specifications

I have created two bootable USBs using balenaEtcher on a mac and Rufus on a a PC for both Ubuntu and Mint (I've just been trying every possible combination like a lunatic). I've also tried this with a new SSD installed and with the old HD (with windows 7 starter installed).

I've made sure the bootable external device is enabled in BIOS and that the boot priority order has the USB option at the top.

When I reboot and hit f11 button it beeps at me until I stop and then displays "operating system not found"

Please help me. Is it even possible to install linux on this machine or should I just give up?